# asp.net mvc making a file link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

ok i have a file link not in the vs 2010 project .basically i have a list page in which i want to show the files , one file each for different organization . how can i make a link to that xml file which exists outside the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to come up with a way to map to the files outside of the project, but ASP.NET MVC will handle everything correctly if you return a `FileAction` like so:

```
return File(@"C:\path\to\whatever.txt", "text/plain");
```

Comment: how will i accomodate the link in the view

Comment: You do not need to.  Just try `return File(@"absolute\path\here.txt")` and see what happens -- it just works.